# Azure CDN not permit Manage

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

Azure not permit modify rules because Manage button is allways disabled, Why?

[image: click to View the image Manage Button]

Answer (score 0):

The management portal is only available for Verizon profiles. Rules Engine editing is only available for Verizon Premium.